# Como pegar uma String que está entre tags com Javascript utilizando Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu tenho a seguinte string:

```
var text = "Meu nome <meuNome@email.com>";
```

Gostaria de pegar apenas o `meuNome@email.com`, utilizando Regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando a API  de regex do Javascript:

```js
var text = "Meu nome <meuNome@email.com>";
var regex = /(<)(.*)(>)/;

console.log(regex.exec(text)[2]);
```

### Explicando

- `//` delimita a área para executar uma regex
- `(<)` procura por uma string que começa com *<*
- `(.*)` Qualquer caracter dentro de *<*
- `(>)` final do recorte que termine com *>*

Essa regex irá retornar um resultado de três grupos, por isso o `regex.exec(text)[2]`, que irá pegar somente o *e-mail*.

Comment: Que maneiro cara, desse seu jeito é mais performático, passarei a usar assim agora, segue o teste: https://jsperf.com/regex-test2017

Comment: Sim @JuniorNunes, e fica melhor a medida que a quantidade de condições aumentam.

Comment: @LucasCosta quais são os 3 grupos? Tenho essa curiosidade.

Comment: O retorno será um array de 3, com `<`, e-mail e `>`. Se der um `console.log(regex.exec(text))` é possível visualizar @Douglas

Comment: Obrigado @LucasCosta

Comment: Curti a solução e também a explicação =)

Answer (score 8):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var text = "Meu nome <meuNome@email.com>";
var email = text.replace(/.*<(.*)>.*/, '$1');

console.log(email);
```

Note que o $1 representa o `(.*)`, entre o `<` e o `>`, que no caso é o email.

Você pode achar mais informações sobre regex [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 4):

O ideal para estes casos é pensar no máximo da informações possíveis que gerem um padrão de captura.

#### Exemplo

Você disse que quer o que esta entre do `<` e `>`

- Você considera que é um email? sim? então poderia definir que deve ter um `@` e quais caracteres especiais serão validos, ex.: `_-.`
- Se não é um e-mail, você considera que pode capturar o próprio `>`? (seu caractere final). ex.: `<var1 > var2>`

#### Resolução

Como eu não sei exatamente o que é a sua captura vou considerar as que citei acima.

- Email : `/<([a-z]+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2})>/i`. [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/W6sWLY/1) **
- Delimitado ai `>` (char final) : `/<([^>]+)>/`. [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/W6sWLY/2)
- Pode ter `>` no meio : `/<(.*)>/`. [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/W6sWLY/3)

Todos os resultado que deseja se encontram no grupo 1.

#### Nota

** : lembrando que você pode adicionar caracteres especiais nas partes de `[`...`]`. ex.: `[a-z_-.]`

#### Adendo

Caso você queira capturar vários de uma vez, basta por a flag `g` no final das regex.

#### Utilização

```js
var text ="Meu nome <meuNome@email.com.br>";
var r = /<([^>]+)>/
console.log(r.exec(text)[1])
```

Comment: Muito bacana sua solução!

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a pergunta já está respondida, mas e se eu quisesse pegar mais de um e-mail?
Essas expressões regulares só estão funcionando pra um e-mail.

Fiz a função abaixo, que embora não utilize expressões regulares, possui a funcionalidade de localizar e guardar o conteúdo entre `<` e `>` de uma ou mais ocorrências.

```html
 <script>
 var texto = "Meus emails são <meuNome@email.com>,<shubiduba@dubiduba.com>  e <lalala@lala.com>";
 
 // Função que localiza conteúdo(emails) entre < e > e guarda em array
 function localizar_tags(texto)
 {
  var emails = new Array();
  i = 0;
  
  while(texto.search("<") != -1)
  { 
   pos_inicio = texto.search("<");
   pos_fim = texto.search(">");
   
   email = texto.substring(pos_inicio+1, pos_fim); 
   emails[i]=email;
   
   texto = texto.substring(pos_fim+1,texto.length); 
   i++;   
  }
  
  return emails;
 }
 
 // Para testar a função
 window.onload=function()
 {
  emails = localizar_tags(texto);
  
  for(i=0;i<emails.length;i++)
  {
   console.log(emails[i]);
  }
 }
 </script>
```